# Understanding of Pytorch NLLLOSS

Tags: pytorch, classification, loss-function

PyTorch's negative log-likelihood loss, [`nn.NLLLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.NLLLoss.html) is defined as:

[image]

So, if the loss is calculated with the standard weight of one in a single batch the formula for the loss is always:

> -1 * (prediction of model for correct class)

**Example:**

[image]

*Correct Class = 0*

*prediction of model for correct class = 0.5*

*loss = -1 * 0.5*

So, why is it called the "negative log-likelihood loss", if there isn't a log function involved in calculating the loss?
​

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Indeed no `log` is being used to compute the result of `nn.NLLLoss` so this can be a little confusing. However, I believe the reason why it was called this way is because it *expects* to receive log-probabilities:

> The input given through a forward call is expected to contain log-probabilities of each class. - [*docs*](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.NLLLoss.html?highlight=log)

In the end it does not make much sense to have it in the name since you might as well want to apply this function on non-log-probabilities...

Comment: What bad naming. It had me puzzling for 2 days if I understood something wrong. Thanks for explaining!